# SSIS import data to check constraint enabled table

Tags: sql, ssis

How to handle Data Import to a Destination Table which has Check Constraint on Date Fields. Without affecting the Destination Table schema, is it possible to insert the data. Do an exception will occur on importing data which does not fall on the date range mentioned in the check constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes an exception will occur and you would not be able to insert unless you turn off the constraint or change the table schema. To turn off the constraint  -

`ALTER TABLE YourTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT YourContraintName`